# Android: Google Play Services location problems

Tags: android

I have a problem with the new Google Play Service and its GPS function.

Right now I am using this code:

```
package my.app.client;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Using location settings.
 * <p/>
 * Uses the {@link com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsApi} to ensure that the device's system
 * settings are properly configured for the app's location needs. When making a request to
 * Location services, the device's system settings may be in a state that prevents the app from
 * obtaining the location data that it needs. For example, GPS or Wi-Fi scanning may be switched
 * off. The {@code SettingsApi} makes it possible to determine if a device's system settings are
 * adequate for the location request, and to optionally invoke a dialog that allows the user to
 * enable the necessary settings.
 * <p/>
 * This sample allows the user to request location updates using the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting
 * (as specified in AndroidManifest.xml). The sample requires that the device has location enabled
 * and set to the "High accuracy" mode. If location is not enabled, or if the location mode does
 * not permit high accuracy determination of location, the activity uses the {@code SettingsApi}
 * to invoke a dialog without requiring the developer to understand which settings are needed for
 * different Location requirements.
 */
public class NewGPSClient extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {

    protected static final String TAG = "location-settings";

    /**
     * Constant used in the location settings dialog.
     */
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    // Keys for storing activity state in the Bundle.
    protected final static String KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES = "requesting-location-updates";
    protected final static String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    protected final static String KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING = "last-updated-time-string";

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Stores the types of location services the client is interested in using. Used for checking
     * settings to determine if the device has optimal location settings.
     */
    protected LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;

    // UI Widgets.
    protected Button mStartUpdatesButton;
    protected Button mStopUpdatesButton;
    protected TextView mLastUpdateTimeTextView;
    protected TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    protected TextView mLongitudeTextView;

    /**
     * Tracks the status of the location updates request. Value changes when the user presses the
     * Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons.
     */
    protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    /**
     * Time when the location was updated represented as a String.
     */
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        // Locate the UI widgets.
        /*mStartUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_updates_button);
        mStopUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_updates_button);
        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_time_text);*/

        Log.e(TAG, "NEWGPSCLIENT created successfully!");


        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        // Update values using data stored in the Bundle.
        //updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

        // Kick off the process of building the GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, and
        // LocationSettingsRequest objects.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();


        startLocationUpdates();

    }

    /**
     * Updates fields based on data stored in the bundle.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState The activity state saved in the Bundle.
     */
    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Update the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates from the Bundle, and make sure that
            // the Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons are correctly enabled or disabled.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES)) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                        KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES);
            }

            // Update the value of mCurrentLocation from the Bundle and update the UI to show the
            // correct latitude and longitude.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(KEY_LOCATION)) {
                // Since KEY_LOCATION was found in the Bundle, we can be sure that mCurrentLocation
                // is not null.
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            }

            // Update the value of mLastUpdateTime from the Bundle and update the UI.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING)) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING);
            }
            updateUI();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
     * LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
     * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
     * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
     * the AndroidManifest.xml.
     * <p/>
     * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
     * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Location Provider API returns location updates that are
     * accurate to within a few feet.
     * <p/>
     * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
     * updates.
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Uses a {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest.Builder} to build
     * a {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest} that is used for checking
     * if a device has the needed location settings.
     */
    protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Check if the device's location settings are adequate for the app's needs using the
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsApi#checkLocationSettings(GoogleApiClient,
     * LocationSettingsRequest)} method, with the results provided through a {@code PendingResult}.
     */
    protected void checkLocationSettings() {
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest
                );
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }

    /**
     * The callback invoked when
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsApi#checkLocationSettings(GoogleApiClient,
     * LocationSettingsRequest)} is called. Examines the
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult} object and determines if
     * location settings are adequate. If they are not, begins the process of presenting a location
     * settings dialog to the user.
     */
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                startLocationUpdates();
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                        "upgrade location settings ");

               /* try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                    // in onActivityResult().
     //               status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                }*/
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                        "not created.");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Start Updates button and requests start of location updates. Does nothing if
     * updates have already been requested.
     */
    public void startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        checkLocationSettings();
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Stop Updates button, and requests removal of location updates.
     */
    public void stopUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest,
                this
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
                //setButtonsEnabledState();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Updates all UI fields.
     */
    private void updateUI() {
        //setButtonsEnabledState();
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    /**
     * Disables both buttons when functionality is disabled due to insuffucient location settings.
     * Otherwise ensures that only one button is enabled at any time. The Start Updates button is
     * enabled if the user is not requesting location updates. The Stop Updates button is enabled
     * if the user is requesting location updates.
     */
    /*private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }*/

    /**
     * Sets the value of the UI fields for the location latitude, longitude and last update time.
     */
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(mLastUpdateTime);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                this
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                //setButtonsEnabledState();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
        // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
        // location updates if the user has requested them.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");


        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            updateLocationUI();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback that fires when the location changes.
     */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateLocationUI();
        /*Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_updated_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    /**
     * Stores activity data in the Bundle.
     */
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES, mRequestingLocationUpdates);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mCurrentLocation);
        savedInstanceState.putString(KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING, mLastUpdateTime);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Which is more or less an example code of the newest Play Store location services. Anyway if I want to activate the service by using this code:

```
NewGPSClient GPSM = new NewGPSClient();
    GPSM.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

There is the following error log I get:

> 05-09 18:45:11.344: I/location-settings(14284): Building GoogleApiClient
>   05-09 18:45:11.344: D/AndroidRuntime(14284): Shutting down VM
>   05-09 18:45:11.344: W/dalvikvm(14284): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4180ac08)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284): Process: my.app.client, PID: 14284
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{my.app.client/my.app.client.LauncherActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2449)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getMainLooper(ContextWrapper.java:109)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.(Unknown Source)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at my.app.client.NewGPSClient.buildGoogleApiClient(NewGPSClient.java:183)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at my.app.client.NewGPSClient.onCreate(NewGPSClient.java:142)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at my.app.client.LauncherActivity.onCreate(LauncherActivity.java:97)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5541)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
>   05-09 18:45:11.349: E/AndroidRuntime(14284):    ... 11 more

So with that new code I get the following errors anyway:

> 05-09 22:10:22.809: W/dalvikvm(25531): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4180ac08)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531): Process: my.app.client, PID: 25531
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{my.app.client/my.app.client.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.app.client.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.app.client-68.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.app.client-68, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2321)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2509)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:172)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5694)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "my.app.client.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.app.client-68.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.app.client-68, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2312)
>   05-09 22:10:22.809: E/AndroidRuntime(25531):    ... 11 more

So here the manifest:

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="my.app.client"
    android:versionCode="59"
    android:versionName="2.7.1" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


        <service android:name="my.app.client.Client" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Client" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    <service android:name=".GPSClient">
         <intent-filter>
             <action android:name=".GPSClient" />
         </intent-filter>
    </service>
        <activity android:name="my.app.client.LauncherActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

In fact, the GPS is now in the class LauncherActivity.

Answer (score 6):

I was receiving a `NoClassDefFoundError` and it was because I had included `play-services-gcm` but forgot to include `play-services-location`.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.5.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.5.0'
```

Not 100% related to your error, but this post is in the top 10 when googling `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices" on path`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get your code working with a couple minor changes, and just used the latitude, longitude, and last update time to test it (I just un-commented the lines pertaining to those fields).

First of all, you should never create the Activity using `new NewGPSClient();`.

Instead, use `startActivity()` like below:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(this, NewGPSClient.class);
 startActivity(i);
```

Second, you were calling `startLocationUpdates();` before the asynchronous call to connect to the SDK had completed.

I moved the call to `startLocationUpdates();` into `onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)`, and now it works.

Here is the full working code:

```
public class NewGPSClient extends ActionBarActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener,
        ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult> {

    protected static final String TAG = "location-settings";

    /**
     * Constant used in the location settings dialog.
     */
    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    /**
     * The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
     */
    public static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    /**
     * The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
     * than this value.
     */
    public static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    // Keys for storing activity state in the Bundle.
    protected final static String KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES = "requesting-location-updates";
    protected final static String KEY_LOCATION = "location";
    protected final static String KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING = "last-updated-time-string";

    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Stores parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
     */
    protected LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    /**
     * Stores the types of location services the client is interested in using. Used for checking
     * settings to determine if the device has optimal location settings.
     */
    protected LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;

    /**
     * Represents a geographical location.
     */
    protected Location mCurrentLocation;

    // UI Widgets.
    protected Button mStartUpdatesButton;
    protected Button mStopUpdatesButton;
    protected TextView mLastUpdateTimeTextView;
    protected TextView mLatitudeTextView;
    protected TextView mLongitudeTextView;

    /**
     * Tracks the status of the location updates request. Value changes when the user presses the
     * Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons.
     */
    protected Boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates;

    /**
     * Time when the location was updated represented as a String.
     */
    protected String mLastUpdateTime;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        // Locate the UI widgets.
        /*mStartUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_updates_button);
        mStopUpdatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_updates_button);
        */
        mLatitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude_text);
        mLongitudeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude_text);
        mLastUpdateTimeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.last_update_time_text);

        Log.e(TAG, "NEWGPSCLIENT created successfully!");


        mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
        mLastUpdateTime = "";

        // Update values using data stored in the Bundle.
        //updateValuesFromBundle(savedInstanceState);

        // Kick off the process of building the GoogleApiClient, LocationRequest, and
        // LocationSettingsRequest objects.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        createLocationRequest();
        buildLocationSettingsRequest();


        //startLocationUpdates(); //Don't call this here, the SDK is not connected yet

    }

    /**
     * Updates fields based on data stored in the bundle.
     *
     * @param savedInstanceState The activity state saved in the Bundle.
     */
    private void updateValuesFromBundle(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Update the value of mRequestingLocationUpdates from the Bundle, and make sure that
            // the Start Updates and Stop Updates buttons are correctly enabled or disabled.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES)) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(
                        KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES);
            }

            // Update the value of mCurrentLocation from the Bundle and update the UI to show the
            // correct latitude and longitude.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(KEY_LOCATION)) {
                // Since KEY_LOCATION was found in the Bundle, we can be sure that mCurrentLocation
                // is not null.
                mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            }

            // Update the value of mLastUpdateTime from the Bundle and update the UI.
            if (savedInstanceState.keySet().contains(KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING)) {
                mLastUpdateTime = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING);
            }
            updateUI();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the {@code #addApi} method to request the
     * LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Building GoogleApiClient");
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request. Android has two location request settings:
     * {@code ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION} and {@code ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}. These settings control
     * the accuracy of the current location. This sample uses ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, as defined in
     * the AndroidManifest.xml.
     * <p/>
     * When the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION setting is specified, combined with a fast update
     * interval (5 seconds), the Fused Location Provider API returns location updates that are
     * accurate to within a few feet.
     * <p/>
     * These settings are appropriate for mapping applications that show real-time location
     * updates.
     */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        // Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
        // inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
        // you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
        // requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
        // application will never receive updates faster than this value.
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Uses a {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest.Builder} to build
     * a {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest} that is used for checking
     * if a device has the needed location settings.
     */
    protected void buildLocationSettingsRequest() {
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Check if the device's location settings are adequate for the app's needs using the
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsApi#checkLocationSettings(GoogleApiClient,
     * LocationSettingsRequest)} method, with the results provided through a {@code PendingResult}.
     */
    protected void checkLocationSettings() {
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result =
                LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(
                        mGoogleApiClient,
                        mLocationSettingsRequest
                );
        result.setResultCallback(this);
    }

    /**
     * The callback invoked when
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.SettingsApi#checkLocationSettings(GoogleApiClient,
     * LocationSettingsRequest)} is called. Examines the
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult} object and determines if
     * location settings are adequate. If they are not, begins the process of presenting a location
     * settings dialog to the user.
     */
    public void onResult(LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");
                startLocationUpdates();
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Show the user a dialog to" +
                        "upgrade location settings ");

               /* try {
                    // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the result
                    // in onActivityResult().
     //               status.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                }*/
                break;
            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be fixed here. Dialog " +
                        "not created.");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            // Check for the integer request code originally supplied to startResolutionForResult().
            case REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User agreed to make required location settings changes.");
                        startLocationUpdates();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Log.i(TAG, "User chose not to make required location settings changes.");
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Start Updates button and requests start of location updates. Does nothing if
     * updates have already been requested.
     */
    public void startUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        checkLocationSettings();
    }

    /**
     * Handles the Stop Updates button, and requests removal of location updates.
     */
    public void stopUpdatesButtonHandler(View view) {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }

    /**
     * Requests location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                mLocationRequest,
                this
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;
                //setButtonsEnabledState();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Updates all UI fields.
     */
    private void updateUI() {
        //setButtonsEnabledState();
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    /**
     * Disables both buttons when functionality is disabled due to insuffucient location settings.
     * Otherwise ensures that only one button is enabled at any time. The Start Updates button is
     * enabled if the user is not requesting location updates. The Stop Updates button is enabled
     * if the user is requesting location updates.
     */
    /*private void setButtonsEnabledState() {
        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mStartUpdatesButton.setEnabled(true);
            mStopUpdatesButton.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }*/

    /**
     * Sets the value of the UI fields for the location latitude, longitude and last update time.
     */
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
            mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.valueOf(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
            mLastUpdateTimeTextView.setText(mLastUpdateTime);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Removes location updates from the FusedLocationApi.
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        // It is a good practice to remove location requests when the activity is in a paused or
        // stopped state. Doing so helps battery performance and is especially
        // recommended in applications that request frequent location updates.
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient,
                this
        ).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                //setButtonsEnabledState();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Within {@code onPause()}, we pause location updates, but leave the
        // connection to GoogleApiClient intact.  Here, we resume receiving
        // location updates if the user has requested them.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Stop location updates to save battery, but don't disconnect the GoogleApiClient object.
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            stopLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GoogleApiClient");

        startLocationUpdates(); //add this here

        // If the initial location was never previously requested, we use
        // FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation() to get it. If it was previously requested, we store
        // its value in the Bundle and check for it in onCreate(). We
        // do not request it again unless the user specifically requests location updates by pressing
        // the Start Updates button.
        //
        // Because we cache the value of the initial location in the Bundle, it means that if the
        // user launches the activity,
        // moves to a new location, and then changes the device orientation, the original location
        // is displayed as the activity is re-created.
        if (mCurrentLocation == null) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
            updateLocationUI();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback that fires when the location changes.
     */
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        mLastUpdateTime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        updateLocationUI();
        /*Toast.makeText(this, getResources().getString(R.string.location_updated_message),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
    }

    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
    }

    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    /**
     * Stores activity data in the Bundle.
     */
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean(KEY_REQUESTING_LOCATION_UPDATES, mRequestingLocationUpdates);
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mCurrentLocation);
        savedInstanceState.putString(KEY_LAST_UPDATED_TIME_STRING, mLastUpdateTime);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I just tried it, but it seems not to work unfortunately. I already had doubts about my phone, but I tried an old version an app using Play Services and everything worked fine then. I edited the errors I get with the code from above into the first post.

Comment: I do start it like you suggested me to with startActivity(i);. In the Android properties of the services lib "Google APIs" v22 is checked and the project itself has the same setting.

Comment: @user3727877 It looks like you just need to update your AndroidManifest.xml file, and change `MainActivity` to `NewGPSClient`, since you changed the name of the class.

Comment: Ok, I changed it now to the launching activity. As long as I won't execute any function it is alright and there is nothing blocking anything, even though I get the following info: "Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzh". Isnt that because of an older version of Play Services on the phone?

Comment: @user3727877 what version of Google Play Services does your device have?  You can check it in Application Manager.

Comment: I just tried to add the library again as I think there should be just a configuration problem here. So I ve seen in the console now the error "google-play-services_lib] Unable to resolve target 'android-9'". I got the lib through SDK Manager and imported it. There is no target in the manifest and the minimum is 8. I will edit the mani in the first post anyway.

Comment: Wow, after half of the day trying to fix that ... the problem was in the properties. I just changed from Google APIs to v. 4.2.2 and now it is working. Thank you for your help! It now works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your **build.gradle** file,

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+"
}
```